# Problem in building imported catkin workspace - Can't see "Fixing Preprocessor ..." in "Projct properties"

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-kinetic, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have read and followed several instructions for importing my catkin workspace in Eclipse. Including:

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse
[2] http://cs460.coins-lab.org/index.php?title=Eclipse

So I have got the required knowledge.

Then I have successfully built Eclipse project files and imported my ~/catkin_ws/build directory into Eclipse.

I am, however, unable to build my ROS workspace and Projects.

In addition, when I want to "Fix Preprocessor Include Paths" at:

Project Properties --> C/C++ General --> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc. --> Providers tab.

Even I can not see the " Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc" item.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Best regards
Reza

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285553/problem-in-building-imported-catkin-workspace---can%27t-see-%22fixing-preprocessor-...%22-in-%22projct-properties%22/) by [rezafirouzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/34129/rezafirouzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend using the ROS Qt Creator Plugin for ROS Development. I just released the latest version with a custom installers found [here](https://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/qtcreator_ros/downloads/installers/). I am still updating the wiki to reflect this change but [this](https://ros-industrial.github.io/ros_qtc_plugin/_source/How-to-Install-Users.html#qt-installer-procedure) walks you through the installer process but download the Online Installer from the previous link.

---

Originally posted by [Levi-Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27969/levi-armstrong/) with karma: 106 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0